# Triangle inequality with three variables

Tags: real-analysis

could You please help me to prove the inequality
$|x+y|+|y+z|+|x+z|\le |x+y+z|+|x|+|y|+|z|$
for complex numbers $x,y,z$? 
It should somehow follow from the triangle inequality, I suppose. But after two hours of attempts I am still nowhere. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's called the Hlawka inequality.

Comment: Thanks! That helps.